# Windows forms--including windows w/in another window

Tags: windows, winforms

I have an application with one main window.  In the window, you click on a button that spawns other windows.  I was wondering if anybody knew how to keep these spawned windows within the original window and not let it be able to be dragged out of it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# have a look at

- [Introduction to MDI Forms with
  C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mdiformstutorial.aspx)
- [Developing MDI Applications in
  C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ggaganesh/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp11272005225843PM/DevelopingMDIAppplicationsinCSharp.aspx)
- [Working with MDI Forms and Child
  Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa232711(VS.60).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The easier way of doing this (and more advisable) is to make your main form an [MDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983667%28VS.71%29.aspx?ppud=4) container. You can set this in the designer by setting `IsMdiContainer` to true in the properties window for the main form. To add a form to the MDI parent, just set the `MdiParent` property of the new form to the instance of the main form. For example, say this code is in a button on the MDI form:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form newForm = new Form(); // obviously you'd use your own Form class here

    newForm.MdiParent = this;

    newForm.Show();
}
```

However, you *can* add a new Form as a child of an existing Form and it will behave just like any other control, **but you have to set the `TopLevel` property to false before the Form is shown**. Our code would look like this:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form newForm = new Form(); // obviously you'd use your own Form class here

    newForm.TopLevel = false;
    newForm.Parent = this;

    newForm.Show();
}
```

The MDI approach is what's generally recommended, mainly because that's exactly what the feature was designed to do: have a container Form that manages zero or more child Forms.

Comment: is there a way to do this w/o coding?  as in, is it a property on the WinForm?

Comment: @yeahumok: Yes. That's explained in the first paragraph of Adam's answer (starting with the second sentence that begins "You can").

Comment: The TopLevel and IsMdiContainer properties can be set in the designer, but the other code would have to remain.